# Crystal Reports - No data in page header if detail is blank

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Reports XI

Have a report with a page header containing data from a table, detail section which can contain a varying number of records, and a report footer containing a total from the detail section.

The problem I'm having is if the last page does not contain any detail records, none of the data fields in the page header are populated, only the text items appear in the page header, and the report footer appears properly populated.

Any hints on how I can populate the header on the last (total) page of the report if the detail section is blank?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it with a sub-report if the detail section is blank.

Each section of a Crystal template has a specific job/purpose.

- Report Header - Once per report and on FIRST record
- Page Header - Once per page
- Details - Once per record
- Page Footer - Once per page
- Report Footer - Once per report and on LAST record

If you have no records (no Details), you will have no records or data in Report Footer. It's all a matter of the data you are working with. I'm not real sure how you have data in the Report Header unless it's a sub-report.